# How to add gradient layer which fills the view frame exactly

Tags: ios, swift4, cagradientlayer

In my app i'm adding the gradient layer to UIView and UIToolBar but it doesn't fill the views exactly 
[image][image]

```
    let gradient:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame               =  self.vw_gradientForToolBar.bounds
    gradient.colors              = [hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#5d8f32").cgColor,hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#04667f").cgColor]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1), false, 0.0)
    let img : UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    self.toolBar.setBackgroundImage(img, forToolbarPosition: .any, barMetrics: .default)
    vw_gradientForToolBar.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

View Hirarchy

[image]

enter image description here

Comment: check your view hierarchy must have a UIView (that white rectangle) above your view, check if you had added accidentally a view

Comment: No there is no UIView added. I have added UIView constraints which will be equal to to device or superview width. and it is top most view

Comment: can you post an screenshot of your view hierarchy for this screen?

Comment: Added view hierarchy

Comment: I mean the "Debug View Hierarchy" screenshot, when your app is running, sorry

Comment: In your screenshot of DebugView hierarchy I can see the undesired rectangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little tough to tell exactly what you have going on, based on the images you posted, however... This may simplify things for you.

First, keep in mind that Layers do not auto-scale, so when your tool bar changes size (different devices, device rotation, etc), you want your gradient layer to *also* resize. Best way to do that is to use a `UIView` subclass and override `layoutSubviews()`.

So, add this class to your code:

```
class GradientView: UIView {

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        let gradientLayer = layer as! CAGradientLayer
        gradient.colors = [hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#5d8f32").cgColor,hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#04667f").cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    }

}
```

Then in your controller's `viewDidLoad()` function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let vwGrad = GradientView()
    vwGrad.frame = toolBar.frame
    vwGrad.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    self.toolBar.insertSubview(vwGrad, at: 0)

}
```

Note: you would no longer need your `vw_gradientForToolBar` (which, I'm assuming, is a `UIView` connected via `@IBOutlet`).

Comment: What if we added to the UIView. Will this work for UIVeiw also?

Comment: If you add *what* to the UIView? Maybe just give it a try? If what you're trying to do works, great... If not, try and clarify your question.

Comment: Yeah i got it it's working fine for every view which ever i need a gradient. I added some changes to the code. Thank's for the help